# Scala Reflect : use MethodSymbol.returnType

Tags: scala, reflection, type-conversion

I would like to know how I can cast an object asInstanceOf the result of MethodSymbol.returnType

Something like :

```
runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(myObject).reflectMethod(myMethodSymbol).apply().asInstanceOf[myMethodSymbol.returnType.typeSymbol]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why would you want to do something like this?

The only thing that you could achieve here is checking if your object is an instance of runtime class of your method's return type. You can do it like this:

```
val myObject = ...
val myMethodsReturnType = ...
mirror.runtimeClass(myMethodsReturnType).isInstance(myObject)
```

Otherwise, such typecast makes no sense, because typecasting is a compile-time operation.